# Limiting a loop in C

Tags: c

I have wrote a program for an assignment. The problem I am having is that I can not figure out how to make a for loop that limits the amount of data that can be entered. For example, for this assignment the user can enter lets say 100 grades. Any advice on how and where to add the for loop?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Kimberly Brand - IT2240  * 05/17/2022
*/

int main (void) {
    // defines a max  of 100
#define maxnum 100
    int i, grade[maxnum], maxentered;
    i = 0;
    printf ("Welcome! \n");
    printf ("Please enter your grades, enter -1 when finished \n\n");
    // while statemtn accepts numbers over 0
    while (i < 100) {
        printf ("please enter your grade ");
        scanf ("%i", & grade[i]);
        // ends program if - 1 is entered
        if (grade[i] == -1)  { //max entered only accepts 100
            maxentered = i;
            i = 100;
        } else
            i++;
    }
    printf ("Your grades are :\n");
    for (i = 0; i < maxentered; i++)  {
        // displays grade entered
        printf ("%i", grade[i]);
        printf ("\n");
    }
    printf ("Thank you!\n");
}
```

Comment: It would seem that the `while(i<100)` already limits the amount of data read to 100.  It's not really clear what the question is, but complete, workable code would be helpful.

Comment: Just replace `while (i < 100)` with `for ( ; i < 100; )` :-)

Comment: Please note that you could use `break;` instead of setting `i = 100;` inside the loop. BTW, is the *number* of grades that needs to be limited to 100 or are the actual *grades* that cannot be greater than 100?

Comment: You have to keep `i` and then iterate from `0` to `i` in the `for` loop. Instead of setting `i` to  `100` to meet the requirement to end the `while` loop, just call `break` to end it. Also notice there's a case where `maxentered` is never initialized, and that the `while` loop will iterate to 100 even if `maxnum` is less than 100...

Comment: It's conventional to use UPPERCASE names for macros.

Comment: _"a for loop that limits the amount of data that can be entered"_ - `for( int i = 0; i < data_entered; ++i)  { stuff ... }`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that maxentered was not initialized! Can't believe I missed that. I think I have the for looped worked out now. I appreciate all the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while` *is* a looping construct, and you do already limit the amount of data that can be read.

If you initialize `maxentered` to `maxnum` (for the event where the limit is met before the user enters `-1`), and change the bounds of the loop as well (to avoid the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) 100 that may not be kept in sync with the size of the array), this program will work just fine (assuming `scanf` never fails).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Kimberly Brand - IT2240  * 05/17/2022
*/

int main (void) {
    // defines a max  of 100
#define maxnum 100
    int i, grade[maxnum], maxentered = maxnum;
    i = 0;                                            
    printf ("Welcome! \n");                           
    printf ("Please enter your grades, enter -1 when finished \n\n");
    // while statemtn accepts numbers over 0          
    while (i < maxnum) {                              
        printf ("please enter your grade ");
        scanf ("%i", & grade[i]);
        // ends program if - 1 is entered
        if (grade[i] == -1)  { //max entered only accepts 100
            maxentered = i;   
            i = 100;
        } else
            i++;
    }
    printf ("Your grades are :\n");
    for (i = 0; i < maxentered; i++)  {
        // displays grade entered
        printf ("%i", grade[i]);
        printf ("\n");
    }
    printf ("Thank you!\n");
}
```

---

That said, it can be cleaned up somewhat.

Always check the return value of `scanf` is the *expected number of successful conversions* that took place. We are looking for one conversion to occur, so we want the return value to be `1`.

Once the loop is complete, the original indexing variable can be thought of as holding the *length* of the valid entries in the array. This can just be reused as the new bound when accessing the data.

[`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) is the appropriate type for indexing memory and dealing with object sizes. While it does not matter all that much for smaller data structures, it is a good habit to practice.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ENTRIES 100

int main(void) {
    int grades[MAX_ENTRIES];
    size_t len = 0;

    printf("Welcome!\nPlease enter your grades, enter -1 when finished.\n\n");

    while (len < MAX_ENTRIES) {
        printf("Please enter your grade: ");

        if (1 != scanf("%d", &grades[len])) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read input.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        if (grades[len] == -1)
            break;

        len++;
    }

    printf("Your grades are:\n");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf("[#%zu] %d\n", i + 1, grades[i]);

    printf("Thank you!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `i` directly to `100`, you can use a `break` statement to exit the loop.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break

```cpp
// ...
    while (i < 100) {
        printf ("please enter your grade ");
        scanf ("%i", & grade[i]);
        // ends program if - 1 is entered
        if (grade[i] == -1)  { //max entered only accepts 100
            maxentered = i;
            break; // <<< NEW
        } else
            i++;
    }
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to change the **while loop** you have for a **for loop**?

Your while loop already limits the amount of data pretty successfully.

```
while (i < 100) {
        printf ("please enter your grade ");
        scanf ("%i", & grade[i]);
        // ends program if - 1 is entered
        if (grade[i] == -1)  { //max entered only accepts 100
            maxentered = i;
            i = 100;
        } else
            i++;
    }
```

If you where to change **(i < 100)** for **(i < 5)** your code would limit the amount of entries in the array to 5 even though it could store 100 entries.

But a **for-loop** is probably better than a while loop in this scenario. It would look something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){

//And then just add the code you want to execute inside
//I would recommend using a 'break;' statement instead of relying
//on 'i = 100' to break out of the loop.

}
```

As a side note, you never gave **maxentered** a default value, so your program will crash if you never type **-1** but instead type as many grades as your loop lets you.